# Telerik ReportViewer Cors Error

Tags: telerik-reporting

I'm trying to use Telerik Reporting MVC but when i run this code

$(window).load(function () {

```
    $("#reportViewer1")
        .telerik_ReportViewer({
            serviceUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:80/api/reports/",
            templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html',
            reportSource: {
                report: "Vehicles.trdx",
                //parameters: {
                //    ReportYear: "2003"
                //}
            },
            viewMode: "ViewModes.INTERACTIVE",
            scaleMode: "ScaleModes.SPECIFIC",
            scale: "1.0"
        });
});
```

I always get a message saying:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63600' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Please Read this document it will solve your problem [Enable CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Add Following lines in your Web.Config under System.WebServer section

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```